# Importing Json File to Html List

Tags: html, jquery, json

I have a JSON file that i want to import into an html list. The JSON is listed below.

The file name is cities.json

```
{
    "cities": [
        "Raofeng",
        "Vostochnyy",
        "Haokou",
        "Shangqing",
        "Igreja",
        "Gémeos"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the CORS Problem I created a cities.json at github just for testing. You should provide your cities.json at your Webserver.

Your JSON

```
{
    "cities": [
        "Raofeng",
        "Vostochnyy",
        "Haokou",
        "Shangqing",
        "Igreja",
        "Gémeos"
    ]
}
```

HTML

```html
<body>
    <div id="cities"></div>
</body>
```

JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getCities = new Promise(
        function (resolve) {
        $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bmehler/mycsv/main/cities.json", function(data) { 
            resolve(data);
        });     
        }
    );
    
    var markup = '';

    getCities
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log('data', data);
            markup = '<ul>'
            $.each( data, function( key1, value1) {
                $.each( value1, function( key2, value2 ) {
                    markup += '<li>' + value2 + '</li>';
                });
            });
            markup += '</ul>';
            console.log('markup', markup);
            $("#cities").append(markup);

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
    });
});
```